# How to extract a portion of a string in c++?

Tags: c++, string

I have a string as below:

```
string str="university";
```

and i want to take a portion if this str like "versi" and save it to another string
how do i do that?

thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about completely trivial code that even day 1 programmers won't find useful.

Comment: Why can't you read documentation before asking on forum. It would be faster!

Answer (score 3):

Use [`substr()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) member function:

```
std::string portion = str.substr(start_index, size);
```

Read the [online doc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) for better understanding. **Read an introductory book on C++ as well**.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Read carefully some documentation about [std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/). You want to use the [substr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) member function.